# JFrame's Border Layout Positioning Not as Expected

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, layout-manager

I'm trying to create a Java Program that does this,

A Frame with

**NORTH** ;Description:Two Button Listener

**CENTRE**:Description: Click Button1 to change solidcolor circle and Button2 to change gradient circle

**SOUTH**: I want 2 buttons ,Button 1 and Button 2

**WEST**: A Circle with a gradient colour

**EAST**:A circle with a solid colour

It's fairly Simple , *when I click a button the respective circle's colour should change*

The code is as follows ..

```
import javax.swing.*;//for the frame etc
import java.awt.*;//for  paintComponent(),Grapics Object etc
import java.awt.event.*;//for listeners


class CircleGradientColor extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
     
    Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;//cast 
    int r1=(int)(Math.random()*255);
    int g1=(int)(Math.random()*255);
    int b1=(int)(Math.random()*255);
    
    int r2=(int)(Math.random()*255);
    int g2=(int)(Math.random()*255);
    int b2=(int)(Math.random()*255);
    Color startcolor=new Color(r1,g1,b1);
    Color endcolor=new Color(r2,g2,b2);
    GradientPaint gradient=new GradientPaint(10,10,startcolor,70,70,endcolor);
    g2d.setPaint(gradient);//here it aint set color for a Graphics2D object
    g2d.fillOval(10,10,60,60);//fills with the Current PaintBrushColor
    }

}

class CircleSolidColor extends JPanel//this class will contain code for the circle
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
    int r=(int)(Math.random()*255);//generate random float between 0 & 255
    int b=(int)(Math.random()*255);//generate random float between 0 & 255
    int gr=(int)(Math.random()*255);//generate random float between 0 & 255
    Color randcolor=new Color(r,gr,b);//name clashed with Graphics g
    g.setColor(randcolor);
    g.fillOval(10,10,60,60);
    }
}

public class TwoButtonGui 
{
JFrame frame;
CircleSolidColor circlesolidcolor;
CircleGradientColor circlegradientcolor;
JButton b1;
JButton b2;
JLabel toplabel;
JLabel centerlabel;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    TwoButtonGui twobuttongui=new TwoButtonGui();
    twobuttongui.go();
    }

public void go()
{
frame=new JFrame();

toplabel=new JLabel("Example of Multiple Action Listeners");
centerlabel=new JLabel("Click The respective Button to change circle Color");
b1=new JButton("Click to change solid");
b2=new JButton("Click to change Gradient");
b1.addActionListener(new CircleSolidColorListener());
b2.addActionListener(new CircleGradientColorListener());

circlesolidcolor=new CircleSolidColor();
circlegradientcolor=new CircleGradientColor();
frame.setSize(1000,1000);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,toplabel);
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,b1);
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,b2);

//if i add 2 SOUTH position i though first will go left and second right 
//IS it so
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,centerlabel);
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST,circlesolidcolor);
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST,circlegradientcolor);
frame.setVisible(true);

}
//inner class for solidlistener
class CircleSolidColorListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1)
    {
    circlesolidcolor.repaint();
    }
}


class CircleGradientColorListener implements ActionListener
{
    public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e2)
    {
    circlegradientcolor.repaint();
    }
}

}//main class ends
```

*But the output I get is rather absurd*

[image: Screen Shot of the Swing Program Output]

Where  am I going Wrong , I know it can be corrected using multiple Panels and LayoutMangaers etc but is there a way to get the results I described  without all that?
I wrote the program as a variant of an example in ***Headfirst Java*** which seems to work just fine with (2 buttons , a label and a Circle ), so why doesn't this work , can I add 2 components in a single position like say BorderLayout.SOUTH as described in my comments,
Thanks!

Comment: _"can I add 2 components in a single position like say BorderLayout.SOUTH"_ - Nope

Comment: As of `JDK 1.4`, Java is encouraging the use of `BorderLayout` constants as `PAGE_START, LINE_START, CENTER, LINE_END and PAGE_END` instead of `NORTH, WEST, CENTER, EAST and SOUTH`, please try to use the new names. And for adding two components in the same location, is simply not allowed in Swing. The component added in the last place, will be kept and rest are removed from that slot.

Comment: _"I know it can be corrected using multiple Panels and LayoutMangaers"_ - That's what I would do

Comment: Ok but why don’t the circle appear correctly then

Comment: You are failing to call `super.paintComponent(g)` too, in the overridden function. Moreover, there is no size defined for the extended `JPanel`.

Comment: I can understand why only one button is shown , but why aren't the 2 circles painted EAST and WEST , I don’t see anything appear there ?

Comment: No ,it works if I position the circle like say frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTRE,solidcolorcircle),but the circle is printed in the Top left instead

Comment: Since, when at `CENTER`, the `JPanel` is stretched to the size manually set by you, for the top level container, i.e. `1000, 1000`. God knows, why these hard coded values.

Comment: Just do like nice cow said and **1.** call `super.paintComponent` in the `paintComponent` method, and **2.** override `public Dimension getPreferredSize()` in each panel. Just tested an it works. I would also `pack()` the frame, rather than `setSize()`

Comment: Thanks its almost Okay now  , except that the center label displays only the first word ...

Comment: Add an update to the code and picture after the changes you made if you still have problems.

Comment: @user1803551 resolved thanks , I messed up my jdk so can't update , will do so asap

Answer (score 1):

North,  is correct.

South,  adding b2 will overwrite b1,  what you want to do is create a new container like JPanel and add b1 to b2 to that container. Then add this container to south. This new container can use GridLayout(1,2)

Center, is correct.

East and west,   the components are 'blank'  so the default size giving by layout manager is none ( painting in the container background != isNotBlank() ). You can however use circles*.setPrefferredSize(dimension) to force a size on them.